# How to convert vertical list of data into horizontal in Excel

Tags: excel, csv, vcf-vcard

I'm trying to export contacts from my dad's old Nokia phone into an iPhone. Their old software Nokia PC Suite can export those contacts into CSV and into pure text which is formatted like this:

```
First Name: ...
Last Name: ...
Phone: ...

First Name: ...
Last Name: ...
Phone: ...

...
```

Note#1: Sometimes there isn't *first name*, just *last* and *phone number*. They are spaced out with line break.

The problem with CSV is that the encoding is messed up and I can't find out what it is. I would like to know how can I export the contacts into the CSV or even vCard from this pure text.

Expected result:

```
First Name | Last Name | Phone
FirstName1 | LastName1 | #####1
FirstName2 | LastName2 | #####2
FirstName3 | LastName3 | #####3
```

**edit**: Note #2: There are over 600 contacts.
**edit#2**: 
[image]'
Here's an example. Left side is source, right side is how I need it for the CSV file. BTW don't mind those "A"s, it's just a priority thing that my father uses...

Comment: VBA would be the best method.

Comment: VBA is best, if there are a lot of contacts. If there aren't too many you can use Transpose function. Copy each set one at a time, pick the cell to the right of first name and do paste special and click the transpose checkbox on the bottom right of paste special

Comment: Can you show some of the more nuanced ways the data could be shown? Meaning, can you show one where two names are given, two phone numbers, etc. and how you expect to handle that? Or if anything, would it just have a blank first name, last name, or phone number?  Does my formula work or is it not too helpful given the various ways your data is kept?

Comment: @BruceWayne I added example to my question

Comment: @BruceWayne It is actually good, I just gotta change it for 2 inputs because at first I didn't notice that only first few contacts had first name as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured a way to get it done without a VBA macro/UDF.

It's one basic formula, with a slight change per column.

Here's the layout I tested with:
[image]

So, with your data starting in A1, and with a break between each "block", you can do this in `C2`:

`=RIGHT(OFFSET($A1,(ROW()-2)*3,0),LEN(OFFSET($A1,(ROW()-2)*3,0))-SEARCH(":",OFFSET($A1,(ROW()-2)*3,0)))` and drag *down*.

Then, use that same formula in `D2`, except change `$A1` to `$A2` wherever `$A1` appears.

In `E2`, same formula, but change `$A1` to `$A3` each time `$A1` appears and drag down.

Edit: Or, you can place this in `C2`, and drag over and down. It's one formula that doesn't need to be edited each column:

```
=RIGHT(OFFSET(INDIRECT("$A"&ROW()-1+COLUMN()-3),(ROW()-2)*3,0),LEN(OFFSET(INDIRECT("$A"&ROW()-1+COLUMN()-3),(ROW()-2)*3,0))-SEARCH(":",OFFSET(INDIRECT("$A"&ROW()-1+COLUMN()-3),(ROW()-2)*3,0)))
```

Comment: The problem is that, as per the OP `Sometimes there isn't first name` which means there is no pattern to exploit.  Sometimes it is two and sometimes it is three.

Comment: @ScottCraner - D'oh. I skipped over that in my zeal to work this out. Oh well, worth a shot!  Even if there's no first name, it'll return nothing, which still works.  It's when there's more than one first name that it'll not look like I bet OP wants. It'll put both names in the "First Name" cell

Comment: I was headed down the same path when I saw that.

Comment: It would be a simple vba, but as it is a one off, and the OP has not shown any effort...I am already bored.

Comment: I just went quickly through the contacts and there are just 9 of them with the first name and the rest is just last name and number so this should be usable. I'm going to try it out and I will let you know! :)

Comment: @ScottCraner I'm sorry that I open Excel once in a few months and I had no idea that VBA even existed...

Comment: Okay, it worked, in the end I used this: `=RIGHT(OFFSET($A1;(ROW()-2)*2;0);LEN(OFFSET($A1;(ROW()-2)*2;0))-SEARCH(":";OFFSET($A1;(ROW()-2)*2;0)))` I had to change `,` to `;` probably because I'm using Office for Mac... I found out that there are more of those first name last name contacts but I'll just cut them out of there by hand. Thanks!

Comment: @effeKtSVK - Není zač!